# js help needed with setting up event paramaters

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a great multiple-file upload script out there, totally flash free:

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Now, while it works for me, I'd like some code to be executed when the upload is done. I think the script provides this functionality, in examples it has this:

```
onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){}
```

but I'm not sure how I'd use it - I just need to have some code executed after the upload is successfully finished.

Sorry if it's a script-specific question, looked to me like it may be general js knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{}` denotes the function body. Here it is expanded:

```
onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
    //this is where you do something on completion.
    //you have access to the id, the filename and the JSON.
}
```

So, for example:

```
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
    element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
    action: '/server-side.upload',
    // additional data to send, name-value pairs
    params: {
        param1: 'value1',
        param2: 'value2'
    },
    onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJSON) {
        alert(fileName + ' was successfully uploaded');
    }
});
```

When it has completed, uploader will execute the `onComplete` function, passing in the id, filename and JSON.

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked great + helped me understand the concept. Is there any way I could know when all uploads are complete?

Comment: @Freelancer HTH :) If you're uploading multiple files, you'd need to maintain a list somewhere of those files and their completion status, and in `onComplete` mark each file as complete. Check each time to see if they're all complete.